# Passing a class as type

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I am trying to pass in a type object to pass to the serializer.

```
internal void SerializeXML(Object ObjType, String XMLRoot, Object Output, String Filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObjType), new XmlRootAttribute(XMLRoot));

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(Filename));
        Output = (Type)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
    }
```

And I want to call it by (Main.LanguageList.Language is a class):

```
SerializeXML(Main.LanguageList.Language, "Language", LanguageListFile, InternalLangListXML);
```

I am getting Object is a variable but is used as a type.

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be more elegant to write a *generic* method:

```
internal void DeserializeXML<T>(String XMLRoot, T Output, String Filename)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), new XmlRootAttribute(XMLRoot));

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(Filename));
    Output = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Close();
}
```

And call it like this:

```
DeserializeXML<Main.LanguageList.Language>("Language", LanguageListFile, InternalLangListXML);
```

Also, it'd suggest changing the method to return the result instead of relying on an output parameter:

```
internal T DeserializeXML<T>(String XMLRoot, String Filename)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), new XmlRootAttribute(XMLRoot));

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(Filename)))
    {
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

It can then be called like this:

```
var result = DeserializeXML<Main.LanguageList.Language>("Language", InternalLangListXML);
```

Comment: Deleted my answer in favor of your much better answer. (:-D)